# MS SQL Server 2012 и загрузка файлов в таблицу FileTables

Tags: sql-server, sql

В менеджере MS SQL Server 2012 есть FileTables. В гугуле особо ничего не нашёл.
Кто-то знает, как загружать файлы в таблицу и в дальнейшем с ними работать?

Comment: А как можно переместить файл из одного подкаталога в другой или сразу поместить в нужный подкаталог в пределах FileTable средствами Transact-SQL, если поле [parent_path_locator] недоступно для изменения?
Именно **не средствами файловых операций**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Таблицы FileTable (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff929144(v=sql.110).aspx)

> ... появляется возможность хранить файлы и документы в специальных таблицах на SQL Server, называемых таблицами FileTable, но при этом доступ к ним возможен из приложений Windows без внесения каких-либо изменений в эти приложения, как если бы они хранились в файловой системе.

- [Создание, изменение и удаление таблиц FileTables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg509088(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [Выполнить загрузку файлов в таблицу FileTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg492083(v=sql.110).aspx#BasicsLoadNew)
- ...

Comment: дельный совет: ищите на MSDN гуглом